# How can i check if a directory/file in my for loop is empty?

Tags: bash

So I have this following for loop that enters every directory and it that directory is empty it should leave it and do nothing. However if the directory isn't empty it should move its contents 1 place up and remove the remaining empty directory, but i dont know how to say: if [**$i is empty**] then ....

```
    for i in */*/
    do
      cd "$i"
    if [ -d "$i" ]
    then
        :
    else
        mv ./* ..
        cd -
        rmdir "$i"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Does something bad happen if you run the `mv` command on an empty directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expand the directory contents into an array (portably, using the shell's positional parameter array), then test how many elements it has, ex.

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob
for d in */; do
  set -- "$d"/*
  [ $# -gt 0 ] || continue
  printf '%s: is non-empty\n' "$d"
done
```

Change `shopt -s nullglob` to `shopt -s nullglob dotglob` if you want to include hidden files.

If you don't like using the positional parameter array, bash supports arrays more generally ex.

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob
for d in */; do
  files=( "$d"/* )
  [ ${#files[@]} -gt 0 ] || continue
  printf '%s: is non-empty\n' "$d"
done
```